# Where do I start with the devolopment of an app that works both on Android and Iphone?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, mobile, mobile-application

I'm new to mobile application development. I want to create an app that works both on Android and Iphone. How do I make the information posted by an android user available to an Iphone user? Where do I start? What kind of process should I be looking at? Help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write code once and deploy it to two platforms, you could look into [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/)/[Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/), though I consider those to be highly unacceptable solutions in most cases.

I think your question, however, is more about application/service architecture. What you'll probably end up doing is writing two separate apps and wrapping them around a common service that you provide -- ie, write your endpoints in PHP on a server somewhere, and access them from both the Android and iOS apps that you write.

As an example, you might have an endpoint at `/post/<id>` that returns a JSON response...

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "title": "Some post",
  "content": "Hello World!!"
}
```

And then write code in both the Android and iOS apps to retrieve and display posts. On Android, you could use [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse the JSON. On iOS, you'll need to use other resources to parse it.

Comment: Yes my question was more about application/service architecture. So basically, before writing the app, I should focus more on the server side where I will have the information that I want to be accessible by both platforms?

Comment: Not necessarily. You could write the native app(s) first and populate them with dummy (static) data, and then later on write your endpoints to match it. It really depends on you and your team (if any). It would definitely be beneficial to write at least a simple spec, however, so you can keep track of what your endpoints will need to be. Otherwise, you might end up realizing that you need service architecture changes as you implement it, which will cost you more time.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Now I have a better idea on how to think about the development. Would you have any interesting resource you think I could use for the development of the architecture?

Comment: Read about RESTful services. I don't have any specific resources in mind -- Googling liberally is my approach.